# SqlAlchemy Core and bare exists query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, exists

I have faced a problem where I have to find if the data exists in the table using **SqlAlchemy Core**.

I think the best way to do this query is to use `exists` method, which stops searching as soon as the first item is found. So, I crafted this version of query:

```
conn = self.db.connect()
query = exists().where(cookie_table.c.cookie_id == cookie_id)
result = conn.execute(query)
```

But it produces this error:

```
StatementError: Not an executable clause (original cause: ArgumentError: Not an
executable clause) 'EXISTS (SELECT * \nFROM cookie \nWHERE cookie.cookie_id = ?)' []
```

I tried modifying it a bit (combining with select), but to no avail.

So, eventually I came up with another solution, using `limit(1)`, which works.

```
conn = self.db.connect()
query = select([1], cookie_table.c.cookie_id == cookie_id).limit(1)
result = conn.execute(query).fetchone()
return True if result is not None else False
```

**I have two questions:**

How the task can be achieved with `exists` method?

Is the query with `limit` as efficient as with `exists`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html?highlight=exists#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists), `exists` applies to a `Select` object, and the following examples are provided:

```
# use on an existing select()
s = select([table.c.col1]).where(table.c.col2==5)
s = exists(s)

# construct a select() at once
exists(['*'], **select_arguments).where(criterion)

# columns argument is optional, generates "EXISTS (SELECT *)"
# by default.
exists().where(table.c.col2==5)
```

**What is going wrong with your code then?**

Well, from my understanding, `EXISTS` is not a directive by itself, so trying to *execute* an `exists()` will fail as it is not an executable clause.

To illustrate, you can try with a simple sqlite console:

- `EXISTS(SELECT * from t);` is an error
- `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM t);` yields 0 or 1 as expected.

**How to fix your issue?**

Wrap your `exists()` in a `select()` executable statement:

```
result = conn.execute(select([exists().where(cookie_table.c.cookie_id == cookie_id)]))
```

It should work as expected:

```
>>> print select([exists().where(users.c.name=='test')])
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE users.name = :name_1)
```

Now, should you use `exists` or `limit`? Frankly I have no idea, and I'm not even sure the answer doesn't depend on your database engine...

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and the following error was raised: `ArgumentError: columns argument to select() must be a Python list or other iterable`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the brackets! Editing my answer.

Comment: Thank you! It works with square brackets. Strange, this usage of `exists` is not mentioned in the documentation. I think this is not uncommon operation to determine if something exists in the database.