# SqlAlchemy exists usage

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, exists, pyodbc

I have used exist to check the the existence of data in the database.

I have followed the answer by @icecrime in the following thread.
[SqlAlchemy Core and bare exists query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381604/sqlalchemy-core-and-bare-exists-query#_=_)

I am getting following error when `EXISTS` used as explained in the above thread.

```
*** ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)") u'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * \nFROM [ItemData] \nWHERE [ItemData].[name] = ?)' ('skv',)
```

I am using Sqlalchemy and following is the code I have used.

```
result=conn.execute(select([exists().where(ItemData.c.name == 'skv')]))
```

I have connected to the server using `"mssql+pyodbc//"` prefix. When I have worked on databases with sqlite:, it worked flawless, Is it something very specific to Microsoft sql database accessing?.

PS: I am new to sqlalchemy, apologies for my terminology if wrong.

Answer (score 3):

To start, I tried running an equivalent query on my own SQL Server database:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [ItemData] WHERE [ItemData].[name] = 'skv')
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'.
```

[MSDN documentation shows that this use of EXISTS is not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx), so we go to the [SQL Alchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists) and find that:

> Note that some databases such as SQL Server don’t allow an EXISTS
>   expression to be present in the columns clause of a SELECT. To select a simple boolean value based on the exists as a WHERE, use literal()

Comment: Thanks for the answer with clarification. Can you please let me know how to use literal() in the above select statement. In the SQL documentation, example is given with session object and I am not able to convert/utilize that in my select statement. I have tried few variation at random but none worked. Ex: `conn.execute(exists([select([literal(True)]).where(ItemData.c.name == 'skv')]))` gives following error `*** StatementError: Not an executable clause (original cause: ArgumentError: Not an executable clause)`