# How to test where a sqllite3 returns results or empty in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
cursor = self.conn.execute(query)

        for row in cursor:
            print("song:", row[0])
```

My goal is not to return query result, but to see whether the query return value or not. I don't see there is a way to test on the 'cursor' object. Ideally, I would want to see something like:

This is in Python.

```
 if cursor is Empty(None):
      print("no result")
  else:
     print("result founds")
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Programming language? Framework/API?

Comment: Please see python.

Comment: You also need to specify the library that you're using to execute the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually achieved by using the `EXIST` sql statement. Assuming you are using sqlalchemy, this [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.exists) from the doc or this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381604/sqlalchemy-core-and-bare-exists-query) may be helpful

The easiest is probably to wrap your query with

```
s = select([table.c.col1]).where(table.c.col2==5)
query = exists(s)
result = conn.execute(query).fetchone()
return True if result is not None else False
```